# What is the difference between the `slice` (:) and the `ellipsis` (...) operators in `numpy`?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I came across a code where the author have used the `ellipsis` operator (e.g., [..., 1]) with `numpy` array instead of a `slice` operator (e.g., [:, 1]) to get arrays part.

**My research on the subject:**

1. From [scipy github wiki page](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Indexing) I've learned that both operators perform somewhat similar operations, i.e. return a slice of a multidimensional array.
2. I've went over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation/509377#509377), which have dealt with several slicing techniques of `numpy` arrays, but did not find the elaboration regarding the situation when should you use `slice` operator and when it is necessary to use the `ellipsis`, or if their functionality is identical.
3. From `Example 1` I can't spot any difference between the two operators:

**Example 1:**

```
    import numpy as np

    A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
    A[..., 0], A[:, 0]    # Out: (array([1, 4, 7]), array([1, 4, 7]))
    A[..., 0] == A[:, 0]  # Out: array([ True,  True,  True])
```

**So my question is:**

- What is the difference in using the `slice` vs `ellipsis` operator with the `numpy.ndarrays`?
- Can they be used interchangeably?
- Is there any advantages in using one or the other?

I'd really appreciate an elaboration regarding my question, and thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The motivations behind the two are completely different.

- The ellipsis means *"all the other dimensions (which I can't be bothered to enumerate or am unsure or don't care how many there are) in their entirety"*
- the slice means *"the subset of the current dimension as specified by the starting and ending indices (and stride)"*.

Comment: I see, but can they be used interchangeably in the case of the `Example 1`?

Comment: Not really.  `[..., 1]` could mean `[:,1]` or `[:,:,:,:,1]`

Comment: So why then the outputs are identical? I mean - is there a situation where the outputs would be different?

Comment: That's rather like saying `2+2` gives the same result as `2x2` therefore the plus and the times operator must be the same. On occasion they can give the same result,  but in general they won't. If you do `A = np.zeros((8,6,4))` then print `A[:,1].shape` you'll see it is `(8, 4)` but if you print `A[...,1].shape` you'll see it is `(8,6)`.