# what does Z[...] mean in python? (Z is an array)

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to understand the following code:

```
A = np.arange(3).reshape(3,1)
B = np.arange(3).reshape(1,3)
it = np.nditer([A,B,None])
for x,y,z in it: z[...] = x + y
print(it.operands[2])
```

And I can't figure out what `[...]` is doing.

Comment: Also Related: [What does “three dots” in Python mean when indexing what looks like a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42190783/15497888) and [What is the difference between the `slice` (:) and the `ellipsis` (…) operators in `numpy`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63314098/15497888)

Comment: Note that the code as shown is just a complicated way to compute `A + B`. Not really sure why it would be written that way, unless there is some additional context missing.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-ellipsis-object-do

Comment: It is used here because `z` is a 0d array, created by `nditer`.  A numpy beginner shouldn't be studying `nditer`.  It's complex and doesn't do anything for performance.

Comment: thank you all for the answers. @hpaulj  haha maybe you're right but i still need to know this. i understand that 'nditer' just helps you iterate over arays, so if it's more complex than that i would like you to enlighten me please.

Comment: We try not to iterate over arrays.  `A+B` does this kind of iteration, but in fast compiled code.  Where's this code sample from?

Comment: @NelsonGon thanks for answering, but unfortunately no. in what you sent it explains that [...] means an infinit nested list and i can't see it in my example.

Comment: @hpaulj https://github.com/rougier/numpy-100/blob/master/100_Numpy_exercises_with_hints_with_solutions.md

Comment: That's a so-so list of examples.  This example does what the name suggests, but I wouldn't invest too much time in trying to understand it.  '...' stands for any number of ':' slices, even 0.  Try: `aa=np.array(3); aa[...]=4; aa`

Answer (score 0):

`z` is an element of your output. The most common usecase to modify it is via this statement `z[...] = # something`. The `...` is an ellipsis.
What your code does is basically iterate over `A` and `B` in a nested forloop, and write the output to the third element of the nditer object.Much like the below code.

To read more about ellipsis, see https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis

To read more about python iter output, see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html 
Especially `Iterator-Allocated Output Arrays` section

Comment: `nditer` docs have two major problems.  It claims to be "efficient", and it omits crucial details, such as the nature of the iteration variables.  Too many beginners are mislead.