# TensorFlow - Index by axis

Tags: tensorflow, indexing, slice, axis, tensorflow2.x

I want to index into the last axis of a tensor with an arbitrary shape, except for the last which is 2.

e.g. Let x be of the shape (1,2,2). Index to the last axis by

```
x_0 = x[:, :, 0]    # x_0, x_1 shapes are (1,2)
x_1 = x[:, :, 1]
```

e.g. Let x be of the shape (1,2,3,4,2). Index to the last axis by

```
x_0 = x[:, :, :, :, 0]   # x_0, x_1 shapes are (1,2,3,4)
x_1 = x[:, :, :, :, 1]
```

I've been unable to find any tensorflow function or usage for slicing an arbitrary shape.

I need a general method to index, such that I can always access the last axis for any shape tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slice syntax in tensorflow is very similar to [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy). You can use the [ellipsis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) in that case:

> Ellipsis expands to the number of `:` objects needed for the selection tuple to index all dimensions. In most cases, this means that length of the expanded selection tuple is `x.ndim`. There may only be a single ellipsis present.

In your case,

```
x_0 = x[..., 0]
```

will index the last axis of a tensor with an arbitrary shape.

You can also look at [the answer to the question: What is the difference between the `slice` (:) and the `ellipsis` (…) operators in `numpy`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318166/7370153).